# Linking a rig with actions and animating more

Tags: animation, rigging, linked-data, nla-editor, actions

So I created a character, rigged it using rigify and created a simple walk action. Next I linked it to my scene blender file and created a proxy to work on it. In the scene, I saw the walk action and I added it to the NLA strip. Now, when I try to do anything else, like make him stand, bend, it replaces the walk strip. I tried changing the blend mode to add, but that completely messes up the mesh. How do i go about adding more actions to a linked character with an action of its own.

Comment: Near the blending "add" option, there's the extrapolation setting, did you set it to "nothing"? If not the last new animation pose will be added to the following frames, messing up things.